# Do java programs running on the terminal continue running while Mac laptop is locked?

Tags: java, macos

I have some really long java programs I am running on my Mac laptop. I have gone into system preferences > Energy Saver > Power Adapter and checked "prevent computer from sleeping automatically when display is off." This program exec's some git commands (no remote commands that require internet). The programs appear as if they continued while the computer locked and the screen saver came on, however I am wonder if the computations it preformed were accurately computed.

Comment: If your PC is locked, background processes will continue to run. However, if your PC falls into energy saving mode (or something similiar), the processes will stop

Comment: See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76107/how-can-i-keep-my-mac-awake-and-locked - if your Mac is set up to perform tasks whilst it is locked, you can reasonably assume they are performed accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to print timestamps before locking your mac and see what result have u then

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24062283)

Comment: Andrew Regan, he asked if it's terminal will process if he locks his macbook, so saying to try by himself with a simplecode to see if what he think is true, is a answer,  that's a nosense comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running it in terminal, you can use nohup to disassociate it from the terminal window.

nohup yourProgramName &

The program will run even after terminal window is closed, as long as the system is running.

You can also just write a simple 'starter' script in bash which will run your program and print something to a text file if the program is still running, or it closes, etc.

simplified example:

```
echo "Starting Program"
./yourProgramName
while pgrep -x "yourProgramName" > /dev/null
do
    echo "Running"
else
    echo "Stopped"
done
```

Then start your script with output to file

```
./starter.sh >> log.txt
```